# How to store complete xml with their tags in single row of sql table (php,sql)

Tags: php, sql

I am working on an xml and finally I want to save the xml output in a table inside single row. How can I save it? When I am fetching the output it is shown in the print array, but not showing in the query part and not inserting. Can anyone please help with it?

Code:-

```
 $xmlDoc = new DomDocument('1.0');
 $xmlDoc->xmlStandalone = true;
 $xmlDoc->encoding = "UTF-8";
 //xml values are added here- Can't show
 $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true; 
 print_r($xmlDoc);
```

Query part:-

```
$sql_query = "insert into                    
xml(order_id,xml_text,header,date_add,date_upd,post_response)    values(".$order_id.",".$xml_output.",'','".$cur_time."','".$cur_time."',
                '')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date_updated='".$cur_time."' , xml_text = '".$xml_output."'";
                $result_xml = Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql_query);
```

Comment: _"but not showing in the query part"_ - What query part? Please show us _all_ the relevant code. Currently, there's no code attempting to save anything in a database in your question. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ...if I would guess what the issue is (without seeing the part of the code you're having issues with), it's probably because when you print it, it's a DomDocument object which needs to be converted to string before you can save it in a db. Look into [DomDocument::saveXML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson- I had added the query part. Please check now. Thanks

Comment: In the first code snippet, you have `$xmlDoc` and in your query, you have `$xml_output`? Again, please show us _all_ the relevant code. What happens between those two code blocks is _very_ relevant to the issue. Also, you should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. A single `'` in any of your variables would currently break your query.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I want to confirm that by converting it to the string, can we save it in db?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't you? If it's a string, it's a string. SQL doesn't care what the string represents. It just sees a series of characters.

Comment: It would be recommended to use prepared statements as there will be various quotes etc. in the resultant XML.

Comment: @NigelRen since it is in prestashop, I am using prestashop  query execution functions. The problem is the syntax error due to various quotes.